# WiX versioning of DLL files which do not have .dll file extension

Tags: dll, wix, version

I am writing an installer for a plugin. The plugin is a set of dll files created with a SDK, and renamed to other extensions (such as .dlo, .dle). Using these extensions is mandatory so that the software recognizes them as plug-ins and loads them.

Unfortunately, WiX seems not to be recognizing those as DLL files, and does not manage versions. Which is an issue in my case, since some files are shared between different plugin releases which can be installed together, and must be at the version of the newest plugin release.

Is there a way to tell WiX that these are legit DLL files?

Comment: In my experience WiX actually detects renamed DLLs. Have you checked that the version resource exists and contains correct information?